# Delete function using jsp and servlet

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

Hi can someone help me to figure out where is my silly mistake.
i am trying to find out in internet but couldnot find the best solution. i have a jsp and java controller where i should be able to delete a record from the databas, following is my code. any help will be acknowledge

```
public void doDel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{

        try {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                messageBean mbean = new messageBean();
               int id = mbean.getMesId();
               String sql;
               sql = "DELETE * from message where id =?";
               Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                st = conn.createStatement();
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setInt(1, id);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
                conn.close();
```

Comment: Just concatenate the id to the String. sql = "Delete * from message where id = " + id;

Comment: `Hi can someone help me to figure out where is my silly mistake`, Sorry no magic ball in our hand. What is the exception ? What you are expecting ? How is the current code behaving ?

Comment: @JNL The approach you mentioned in comments can be a security issue because of SQL Injections.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no `*` after `delete`, it's just `delete from`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query as

```
sql = "DELETE from message where id =?";
```

Or otherwise use `statement` query as

```
sql = "DELETE from message where id ="+id;
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-delete-records.htm) for delete query using Statement

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to note:

1. `st = conn.createStatement();` is not needed. Because you are already using PreparedStatement.
2. `sql = "DELETE * from message where id =?";` This can be written as:

   `sql = "DELETE from message where id =?";` //No need of `*`
3. `conn.commit();` is needed only if you are setting `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`

You must provide Error/Stacktrace to get useful answers.